# Multiple projects not showing up on SONARQUBE dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.2

I am trying to show multiple projects on which I run the analysis on my SONARQUBE dashboard. However when I start analyzing a new project, the old one goes away from the dashboard and just the new one shows up.

I am using SONARQUBE 5.2

Can it be achieved? The dashboard should show all the projects on which I run the analysis.

Comment: You're using a 2 year old version of SonarQube, latest LTS is 6.7, you should consider the upgrade in order to get some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, you're using the same `sonar.projectKey` value for each analysis, *forcing* a replacement each time. Provide a unique value for the project key, and you should get the behavior you expect.

*AND* you should upgrade at your earliest convenience. At this writing, the current version of SonarQube is 7.1, and the current LTS is 6.7.3. Note that the migration path from 5.2 is first 5.6.*, *then* 6.7.3, and then optionally 7.1.

Comment: I figured it by myself but Yes, you are right I was making the same mistake by using the same projectKey for different projects. Thanks